# jQuery load() working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, jquery

I have encountered a very strange problem in using jQuery `load()`. I used it to load a php file in a `div` container. It's working fine on my localhost but on the server it does not load the php file and instead gives

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I don't know why is this happening. My jQuery code is:

```
//ADD THE Description TO THE HOLDER
infofield.append('<div id="'+opt.style+' description" class="'+opt.style+' description">'+item.data('desc')+'</div>');

// ATTACHED the comments to the LIGHTBOX
$('.description').load('gallery_comments.php?id='+id+'&pic='+imgsrc+'&a'+ab);
```

Is there a server issue? Using on localhost with WAMP server and testing cross browser compatibility it runs in all browsers, even in IE8. Can any one help?

update ** just used chrome and found out one bug in Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in line 9  and line 9 code is

```
   $(function() {  
  $('div.viewgp').hide(); 
   $('.slidegp').click(function() { 
  $('.viewgp').fadeToggle(200); 
  }); 
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the page directly to see if you get a 500 error?

Comment: It'd be more helpful to see the PHP code in `gallery_comments.php` which is causing the error.

Comment: Check the server's error log, it'll have details about what caused the 500 error. Until you do that, it is impossible to help you, as a 500 can be caused for any number of reasons.

Comment: Yes, the 500 error means something is going wrong in the PHP file.  Try accessing the PHP file directly to debug it.

Comment: yes i have tried to access the file directly . i am able to access it also , dnt knw whats wrong

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the code in php file is very big , i think i should not paste the whole code here . well as far as the server error log . is this possible to chk it on a shared server hosting?

Comment: just found one bug Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at Php line 9 and line is $(function() {  
$('div.viewgp').hide(); 
$('.slidegp').click(function() { 
$('.viewgp').fadeToggle(200); 
}); 
});

Comment: While this additional bug should be fixed, I expect it will be unrelated to your original question. If `.load` is executing, then jQuery has loaded and $ is defined by that point. Otherwise you'd get the same error at the point you attempt `$('description')`. As others have said, the 500 error is purely server side. You need to investigate what query string params you end up sending, and why those particular values cause the server side processing to fail.

Comment: thanks for pointing out me 2 the right direction guys , after reading a server error and no error in firebug i thought might be some server issues but in chrome console i found out one error . and now its fixed thanks @all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you can access gallery_comments.php directly, but with what query string parameters? Are you sure that you use the same ones which are appended via the values of `id`, `imgsrc`, and `ab` in the following line?

```
$('.description').load('gallery_comments.php?id='+id+'&pic='+imgsrc+'&a'+ab);
```

Try the following changes to determine exactly what you're trying to load, and navigate directly to the url that comes to your console or alert box:

```
var url = 'gallery_comments.php?id='+id+'&pic='+imgsrc+'&a'+ab;
console.log(url); // or alert(url);
$('.description').load(url);
```

If I wanted to play [psychic debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/10/10127054.aspx), these would be my first two guesses:

- one of the parameters is required server side, but is null / empty / undefined in your javascript
- There is an attempt to access a resource that is accessible on your localhost environment but not on the remote server environment